# EPR paradox and quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I have just been watching about EPR experiment on Leonard Susskind videos called entanglements and at
the end of the 7 lecture he said that for say two particles of opposite spin up/down and  at long seperation
if you "measure the spin of one you instantly know the spin of other particle". He then said something
like "I don't know why people say action at a distance or paradox etc". He is right that you do immediately
know the state of the other particle if you measure one so there is no problem. however, there are
people everywhere talking about this paradox but it does not seem to be a problem? Who is right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In quantum
mechanics, states can be described as being  in a  [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) of their possible values. This means that each particle after they separate can be described by the state

$$\Psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(  \mid \uparrow \rangle + \mid \downarrow \rangle)$$

which means that each particle is in a *superposition* of the two possible spin states up and down. So now if you measure the state of one of the particles, you will find it in $\mid \uparrow \rangle$ or $\mid \downarrow \rangle$. At this point the particle then has a definite spin state, which would imply that the other particle (no matter
how far away it is) should *instantly* collapse into the opposite spin state (also since spin angular momentum must be conserved).

The implication then is that something instantaneously caused the second particle state to collapse.

Comment: how can a professor in stanford physics be wrong?

Comment: I think he is being subtle with his words. If you restrict yourself to only talking about measurement outcomes, which is how it is usually taught (i.e. Copenhagen), then you can say what he said. There is no way to measure the distant particle from your location faster than light obviously

Comment: This "knowledge"  faster than light exists also in classical situations: Mike and Ike Smith are  brothers, and you hear that one Smith is working in Japan and the other in New York, When you meet Ike  Smith in the New York office, you know faster than light  could convey that Mike  Smith is in Japan.

Comment: I think that is the point the OP is making.